# symbol expected in first line of libre office type definition

Tags: compiler-errors, basic, libreoffice-calc

Talk about a newbie! I can't get my first line to compile.
[Basic syntax error:  Symbol expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asypx.png)

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Type xyz
    Dim sheet as object
    Dim cell as object
    dim range as object
End Type


Sub Main

End Sub
```

Version: 6.0.2.1 (x64)
Build ID: f7f06a8f319e4b62f9bc5095aa112a65d2f3ac89

tools->macros->edit macros>

compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dim](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03102100.html) declares local variables within subroutines. [Type statements](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03090413.html) do not use it.

The reason this error was tricky to diagnose is that it looks like the problem is in `Type xyz`, but that part is fine. The IDE highlights whatever is before the first `Dim` statement, which may be a minor problem of the parser. The following code shows that even a comment can get highlighted!

```vb
Type xyz
    'This comment will be highlighted because of the Dim error.
    Dim sheet as object
End Type
```

This inaccuracy is not unusual for any compiler. Error messages often give clues to problems rather than telling exactly what and where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  I was so focused on the first line that I couldn't see the obvious.